# MySQL INSERT INTO issue

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CauHoi( MaCH VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci PRIMARY KEY, MaMH VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, Question TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, Difficulty VARCHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, a TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, b TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, c TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, d TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, Answer VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
```

And here is my query:

```
answerComboBox->addItem("a");
answerComboBox->addItem("b");
answerComboBox->addItem("c");
answerComboBox->addItem("d");
q.prepare("INSERT INTO CauHoi(MaCH,MaMH,Question,Difficulty,a,b,c,d,Answer) VALUES ('"
          + maCHLineEdit->text() + "','"
          + maMHLineEdit->text() + "','"
          + questionTextEdit->toPlainText() + "','"
          + difficultyComboBox->currentText()+ "','"
          + aLineEdit->text() + "','"
          + bLineEdit->text() + "','"
          + cLineEdit->text() + "','"
          + dLineEdit->text() + "',"
          + answerComboBox->currentText()+");");
```

However when q.exec(), if answerComboBox->currentText()=="c", the Answer column in CauHoi table become cLineEdit->text(). How crazy it is! I just want it be simply "a","b","c","d".

Please help me

Comment: You need to be more careful with your SQL statement. Try to print it out before you prepare it. You are vulnerable to sql injection attacks. To test it, prepare a question about the three musketeers  where one answer is "D'Artagnan".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the beginning and ending single quotes around

```
answerComboBox->currentText()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I'm missing single quotes around answerComboBox->currentText().